# Verify that iOS has navigated from the running app to another application in Xcode UI testing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I have a button in my app that navigates a user to the Mail app to an email dialog. I'm attempting to use Xcode UI testing to verify that this has occurred. The problem is, once I'm in the Mail app, I can't get the context of my currently running application because it has been backgrounded, so I can't verify if any elements are on screen or not. On top of that, Xcode UI testing actually throws an error after it taps the button and navigates to the mail page:

```
<unknown>:0: error: -[MyTests testButton] : UI Testing Failure - Failure getting snapshot Error Domain=XCTestManagerErrorDomain Code=12 "Failed to get main window after 30 retries: kAXErrorServerNotFound (see <rdar://problem/15530121>)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to get main window after 30 retries: kAXErrorServerNotFound (see <rdar://problem/15530121>)}
```

Is there any kind of assertion I can use that verifies that the user has been navigated out of the app into the Mail app?

Answer (score 1):

UI Testing cannot interact with anything outside of your application. Once your app opens Mail.app the framework can no longer interact with the device.

To verify this, try printing out the app's hierarchy once Mail opens. You will notice that nothing in Mail nor the navigation bar will show up - you will only see your app's information.

`print(XCUIApplication().debugDescription)`

Comment: Is there a way to verify the app under test is no longer on screen?

Comment: you could use something like: XCTAssertFalse(XCUIApplication().navigationBars["My App TItle"].exists)

Comment: Update: Afraid that doesn't work, nor does XCUIApplication().exists, since XCUIApplication() cannot be found.  Sorry.